# Java HttpServletRequest getquerystring

Tags: java, http, servlets

In my servlet, req.getQueryString() returns null when an ajax request is sent to it.
Is this because req.getQueryString() only works for GET and not POST?

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {
req.getQueryString();
}
```

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way to get hold of request parameters is to use `request.getParameter()`. This works for both GET and POST requests.

POST requests typically carry their parameters within the request body, which is why the `request.getQueryString()` method returns null.

Answer (score 1):

From [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString%28%29):

> This method returns null if the URL does not have a query string.

Since you are in a `doPost()` handler, we can assume that indeed the request has no query string since it is a POST.

Answer (score 1):

POST request may have a query string, but this is uncommon. POST data is included directly after the HTTP headers that browser sends to the server.